# Excel downloaded as zip file in IE

Tags: javascript, browser, dojo

When I click on link it open the zip file instead of xlsx file.
But the same file is downloaded in FF. Another thing is some of the excel file can be easily downloaded from the same path having the same content but the name is different

I dont know where I am doing the mistake.Is this a naming convention issue?.
One thing is sure that this is not the issue with IE...
I am using dojo for path.

```
var temp = path of excel file

var href = dojo.place('<a href = "'+ temp+ '"> Export </a>',dojo.place());
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Dojo problem.

Instead, the server is probably sending the wrong mime-type in the headers when the browser accesses the URL. [You might be able to work around it with an .htaccess file](https://serverfault.com/questions/19060/why-are-docx-xlsx-pptx-downloading-from-webserver-as-zip-files).

It works in IE only because Microsoft gave it [special-case behavior to handle their own Office file formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx).